# Cross thread operation on the server code

Tags: c#

I am new in server client programming so i wrote this server code

```
namespace TCP_SERVER
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       private ArrayList nSockets;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public void listenerThread()
        {
            new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(8080);
            tcpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Socket handlerSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
                if (handlerSocket.Connected)
                    //try
                    //{
                        {

                            lbConnections.Items.Add(handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected.");
                            lock (this)
                            {
                                nSockets.Add(handlerSocket);
                            }
                            ThreadStart thdstHandler = new
                            ThreadStart(handlerThread);
                            Thread thdHandler = new Thread(thdstHandler);
                            thdHandler.Start();
                        }
                    //}
                    //catch (Exception ex)
                    //{
                    //    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    //}
            }
        }
        public void handlerThread()
        {
            Socket handlerSocket = (Socket)nSockets[nSockets.Count-1];
            NetworkStream networkStream = new
            NetworkStream(handlerSocket);
            int thisRead=0;
            int blockSize=1024;
            Byte[] dataByte = new Byte[blockSize];
            lock(this)
            {
               // Only one process can access
               // the same file at any given time
               Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\KINENE\Documents\submitted.txt");
               while(true)
               {
                   thisRead=networkStream.Read(dataByte,0,blockSize);
                   fileStream.Write(dataByte,0,thisRead);
                   if (thisRead==0) break;
               }
               fileStream.Close();
            }
            lbConnections.Items.Add("File Written");
            handlerSocket = null;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {      
            IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
            lblStatus.Text = "My IP address is " + IPHost.AddressList[0].ToString();
            nSockets = new ArrayList();
            Thread thdListener = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listenerThread));
            thdListener.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

i get the error on this line of code

```
lbConnections.Items.Add(handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected.");
lock (this)
```

Comment: This is not *server* code as it runs within a UI.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing UI elements from another thread, which is not allowed.

You should call `Invoke` to call the code on the right thread:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        lbConnections.Items.Add(handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected.");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much patrick it is now working can we chat via mail

Comment: Glad it helped. Usually I have no off-site chat with other users. If you have further questions, feel free to ask a new question. There are a lot of other people available to help you.

Comment: If you do feel the urge to show your appreciation, contribute to the community by asking good questions and post quality answers, also upvote / accept answers you deem helpful.